# Replacing text in file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am pulling down an XML file from the web and writing it to a local directory.  At the end of the XML file there is a series of tags:

```
  </Product>
 </Products>
</Feed>
```

I want to replace these tags with the contents of another file (which include the tags).  Here is my Powershell I am running:

```
$BVProductFeed = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "[xml web page]" -OutFile "[local directory]" -TimeoutSec 1800000
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("[file to append]")

$mergeFile = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("[xml web page]") -replace ("</Product> </Products> </Feed>",$content) | Set-Content "[updated file]"
```

The script runs fine, it pulls down the XML, opens the $content file just fine, but when it writes the `$mergeFile` it looks the same as the `$BVProductFeed` file initially downloaded.  I am inferring it is a problem with my replace statement.  Do I need to include the CRLF between the tags?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To add more `<Product>` elements to the end of the file? If that is, what you want, then there are far more elegant ways in powershell to do this.

Comment: Oh I am aware there are more elegant ways to do this, however, I have inherited this and until I can fix the process from start to finish, I have to work with what I have.  I am working now to fix the whole process.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the CRLF tags had to be included in the test in order to replace the whole string.  Once I added those in, I was able to do the removal and replacement of text.